# How to compare char variables (c-strings)?

Tags: c++, if-statement, compare

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char word[10]="php";
    char word1[10]="php";

    if(word==word1){
        cout<<"word = word1"<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

I don't know how to compare two char strings to check they are equal. My current code is not working.

Comment: -1 Since the fact they are strings is suspected, try a search: `C++ compare strings`. Modify the terms as appropriate, e.g. `C++ compare c-string`. SO shouldn't be the "goto" reference.

Comment: Oh, I see, the "strings" was edited. I've removed my -1, but heed the previous comment anyway. Searching for the actual problem/issue is usually useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `std::string` objects instead:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string word="php";
    string word1="php";

    if(word==word1){
        cout<<"word = word1"<<endl;
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Use strcmp.

```
#include <cstring>
// ...
if(std::strcmp(word, wordl) == 0) {
// ...
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To justify c++ tag you'd probably want to declare `word` and `word1` as `std::string`. To compare them as is you need

```
if(!strcmp(word,word1)) {
```

Answer (score 2):

word and word1 in your submitted code are pointers. So when you code:

```
word==word1
```

you are comparing two memory addresses (which isn't what you want), not the c-strings they point to.

Answer (score -2):

```
#include <iostream>
**#include <string>** //You need this lib too

using namespace std;

int main() 
{

char word[10]="php";
char word1[10]="php";

**if(strcmp(word,word1)==0)** *//if you want to validate if they are the same string*
    cout<<"word = word1"<<endl;
*//or*
**if(strcmp(word,word1)!=0)** *//if you want to validate if they're different*
    cout<<"word != word1"<<endl;

return 0;``
}
```