# Can't get french characters to work in C++

Tags: c++, unicode

```
// francais projecct test1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char  userAnswer[10];
    char answer[] = { "Vous êtes" };

    wcout << "s'il vous plaat ecrire conjugation pour Vous etre: ";

    cin>>userAnswer;

    if (strcmp(userAnswer, answer) == 0)

        cout << endl << "correct"<<endl<<endl;
    else
        cout << endl << "wrong answer"<<endl<<endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The accented characters aren't recognized by the compiler and I don't know how to get input of unicode characters if unicode is required.

Comment: P.S. there's a circumflex on "plaît" and an acute on "écrire".

Comment: Whilst I'd normally applaud you for trying to use Unicode IO on Windows, if you're only interested in French accents (and console output) then you don't need to: you can cover most of Europe with the default code page.

Comment: My French is really rusty, but it's just occurred to me too: you probably want "écrivez" anyway, not "écrire", as the imperative vous form.

Comment: turns out the program only answers with yes even if the answer is wrong and the accented character are showing up unrecognized in the terminal

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare char variables (c-strings)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355465/how-to-compare-char-variables-c-strings)

Comment: I got the code to work but french character are not recognized by default and when I use wcout it stills comes out the same. any cin inputs with accented characters are unrecognized

Comment: It's more complicated than you think. The accented ê can be encoded differently (http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) and you have platform specific issues. I would prefix your strings explicitly with u8 or L (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and then use std::string or std::wstring.

Comment: ...and you may have to set the console code page, it depends on the platform. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371012/how-do-i-print-utf-8-from-c-console-application-on-windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::getline` is defined for `std::basic_string` (specialized cases include `std::string`, `std::wstring`). Normal character arrays don't fall in that category.

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/

Though I would highly recommend you to use `std::string` / `std::wstring`, If you want to make your code work, you must use `cin.getline` in your case.

You may refer to Example 2 in this:
https://www.programiz.com/cpp-programming/library-function/iostream/wcin

Secondly, `userAnswer == answer` is wrong as it will compare two pointers, not their actual content.

For doing so, you should use `strcmp()`.

Reference: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/

Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char userAnswer[10];
    char answer[] = "Vous etes";

    wcout <<"s'il vous plait ecrire conjugation pour Vous etre: ";
    cin.getline(userAnswer, 10);

    if (!strcmp(userAnswer, answer))
    {
        wcout <<endl<< "correct";
    }
    else
    {
        wcout <<endl<< "wrong answer";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How do I make userAnswer == answer work and make it compare their actual content

Comment: @Juan Do you want to use `char *` or `wchar_t *`? I have separate answers for each two.

Comment: I actually don't know which one to use I used char * in order to reduce red error marks this is my first time interacting with unicode

which is better wchar_t or char can you tell me

Comment: It actually depends on the type of encoding and the platform. See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17871934/5859925. So, I think `char *` is sufficient. I will answer accordingly.

Comment: Use either std::string or std::wstring. No C-Strings and it will work. To compare C-Strings, you need std::strcmp.

Comment: "_`std::getline` is defined for `std::string`._" Is wrong. As per the [documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline), `std::getline` is not tied to a particular class (`std::string`, or `std::wstring`), or particular stream (`std::cin`, or `std::wcin`).

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius Thanks for pointing it out. I have corrected it.